# How to lock screen for a terminal session?

Tags: bash, screen-lock

as we could use `xflock4` command to lock the screen (ask for a password to continue) in an X session; I need a similar way to lock the `tty1` session. Is there any? (`logout` is not working when I call in a script.)

### Edit

Here is my full script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $(id -u) > 0 ]]; then
    if [[ "$DISPLAY" == "" ]]; then 
        sudo "$0" "$(whoami)"
    else
        gksu "$0" "$(whoami)"
    fi
    exit
fi

physlock -d -u $1
pm-suspend
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If vlock doesn't work for you, try [physlock](https://github.com/muennich/physlock). It doesn't inhibit suspension and hibernation which is nice if you want to lock automatically when the computer sleeps. Also, physlock locks all tty's by default.

Answer (score 2):

[`vlock`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/vlock) might be what you're searching for.

Comment: when I use vlock in the script, it says "vlock: stdin is not a terminal" and does not work as expected. I'm searching for a way for that error.

Comment: Should be run as root: `sudo vlock` ...

Comment: That was what I was doing, but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a shellscript solution (which happens to work on `OSX` too), see [bashlock](https://github.com/acornejo/bashlock).